# Is user authorized, on Facebook tab

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

Getting an interesting error. I've been developing and application, and viewing it on it's page. Now I'm install that app in as tab on a company page and it's saying I can't use:

```
<fb:if-is-app-user>
```

in the tab view? How can I show or hide part of the page if the user viewing it is an app user?

Answer (score 1):

FBML fan page tabs have been deprecated and replaced with Facebook iframe pages.  To determine if the user is fan, you will need to decode the signed_request parameter that gets POST'ed to your webpage.  There will be a "liked" variable in the encoded json payload.  This [page](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php) gives an example of how the new process works,